# Application C/C++ MFC on Windows Mobile 5 or 6 Browseable directories

Tags: c++, mfc, directory, windows-mobile

Hello and thank you for reading my post.

I have:

- a Windows PC with an application "pc_app" (C/C++ with the MFC) running.
- a handheld computer running a Windows Mobile OS (5 or 6) with an application "mob_app" (C/C++ with the MFC) running.

From the PC, in the application "pc_app", we can list all the directories in the mobile.

Whereas on the mobile, when "mob_app" instantiates a "CFileDialog" object and shows the list of browseable directories, it proposes only a subset of all the directories in the mobile.
For example:

- if a directory is at depth 2 like this: "\My Documents\dir_1\dir_2", "dir_1" is proposed but not "dir_2".
- The built-in directory "Application Data" is not shown either.
- Etc.

From the PC, we need to copy a SQLite db (a ".db" file) onto the mobile:

- we have to copy it to a directory that "mob_app" can browse afterwards ;
- we also need this directory to have enough space available.

What I would like to know is, from the PC, how can I get the list of directories that "mob_app" can browse and only these directories.

For example, on my mobile, "My Documents", "Program Store", "Storage Card", "My Documents\a_dir"... etc. can be browsed by "mob_app".

I was wondering if maybe this is the mobile which has to give this information to the PC?

Can you help me?
Best regards.

============================================================================

EDIT

Hello Josef.

Thank you for your answer which is very helpful.

According to your last advice, we cannot propose only one volume/location to our users because there might not be enough space on the volume for our application working directory to reside.

We've been trying a few things.

In a loop looking like this:

```
hf = CeFindFirstFile(L"\\*", &FindFileData);

do
{
   [...]
   if(FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY)
   {
     }
   [...]
} 
while(CeFindNextFile(hf, &FindFileData) != 0);
```

we retrieve all the files and directories which are directly below the "root" of the mobile: "My Computer":

- several files like for example "mxip_lang".
- directories: "Application Data", "ConnMgr", "Documents and Settings", "My Documents", "Program Files", "Temp", "Windows"
- the two directories "ProgramStore" and "Storage Card" which particularity is to have the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY` attribute.

On our testing mobile, through our mobile application and "CFileDialog",
we can only see the SQLite databases located in directories directly under `My Document`, `ProgramStore` and `Storage Card`.

For each one, we can determine how much space is available with the `CeGetDiskFreeSpaceEx()` function.

Note that we suppose that "My Documents" is on the "Main Memory" of the mobile.

Given the loop above, can we reasonably propose to our users:

1. "My Documents" which would be on the "Main Memory",
2. all the volumes which have the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY` attribute (we are very uncertain about this).

For each of them we would know the amount of free space available.

Then we would create our specific working directory right under the chosen volume.

Incidentally, we have tried to call the "CeGetSpecialFolderPath()" function with the "CSIDL_DRIVES" flag: "lpBuffer" is empty (""). Our Os is Windows Mobile 5.0 which seems to be based on Windows CE 5.0 and according to the manual you send us "CSIDL_DRIVES" is "Not valid for Windows CE 5.0 and later".

Best regards.

==================================================================

Edit 2

Hello Josef and thank you for your answer.

1) We have tried the pair of functions you suggested: "FindFirstFlashCard()" and "FindNextFlashCard()".

We also tried the functions `FindFirstStore()`, `FindNextStore()`, and for each store: `FindFirstPartition()` and `FindNextPartition()`.

With this set of functions (FindFirstStore(), FindNextStore(), FindFirstPartition() and FindNextPartition()) we could get these informations (see image below and please tell me if you can't see it):
[image: Stores and partitions on our Windows Mobile 5.0 computer]
Thanks to the function `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx()` and if we pass it as an argument either `szVolumeName` or `L"\\"` (in case "szVolumeName" is empty) we could retrieve the volumes available space.

2) We also installed a tool on the mobile to examine it's registry: "Kilmist Registry Editor for Pocket PC".
At one step of the installation, on the mobile, Kilmist requires us to select a location for installing their program.
On our mobile, we are given three choices: "Computer", "Program Store" and "StorageCard" and for each of them the amount of space available.
This is what we would like to achieve with our program.

This is as far as we got for now.
We did this on our particular handheld mobile computer. So it is a specific case.
In general, what information among these (above) shall we analyse to propose a satisfactory set of locations to the user. (As a reminder, we will use this volume to host a directory that we'll use afterwards to copy our SQLite databases).

Comment: Great findings. Why not use the information you get for StoreX and PartitionX. Computer is an alias for the root fs (Store0-Part0), Program Store is the alias for Store2-Part0 and StorageCard an alias for Store3-Part0.

Comment: I can't find documentation about the possible file systems on Windows Mobile/CE especially about "RAWFS", "imgfs.dll" and "fatfsd.dll". I don't know if these denominations are specific to the mobile's OEM... Do you know anything about that? Thanks.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ce_base/archive/2005/08/09/449748.aspx http://www.google.com/patents/US7614051 http://www.developermemo.com/537659/ http://wenku.baidu.com/view/95f969a7284ac850ad024241 IN SHORT RAWFS and IMGFS are reserved for the OS. They hold the firmware system files and the persistent storage.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows CE and Windows Mobile (CE4.2 or CE5 based) standard file dialogs are restricted to \My Documents" plus one subdir below that and 'external' volumes, like SD Card or persistent storage. OEMs declare part of the flash store as persistent storage and use special names for thes like "\Flash File Store", "CK_FFS" and others. You can recognize these Volume names when using the mobile file explorer, these volumes are listed as top level selections in the file browser list box at top.

To overcome this one can write a custom file dialog or use one of the free (and commercial) available libs.

If you want to restrict browsing on PC for the remote file system of a Windows Mobile device connected via ActiveSync or WMDC you need to write a custom browser with either the same restrictions coded in the logic or use RAPI to query the CE ShellFolders: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921197.aspx. The function you would need at last are CeGetSpecialFolderPath(): CSIDL_DRIVES; CSIDL_PERSONAL; CeGetStoreInformation(); CeGetDiskFreeSpaceEx; CEFindFirstFile() and so on. From my point of view it is easier to restrict the PC based browser to a fixed dir.

To find mounted external file systems use FindFirstFlashCard/FindNextFlashCard http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb415506.aspx. This will not only find sd cards but persistent storage file systems too. See also [Finding the storage card path on WM6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40269/finding-the-storage-card-path-on-wm6)

As there is no CE RAPI function for this, you need to write an DLL to be called by RAPI.

Possibly it is easier to enumerate top level dirs and check available space using CeGetDiskFreeSpaceEx for each. Then present the user with a list of these dirs and the available space.

There are other FileSystemManager and StorageManager functions on the device to check finally if a volume (directory) is an external one (CeGetVolumeInfo), but these are all not available direcly via RAPI.

Comment: I just edited my first post for the second time. Tkx.